# NHibernate query and twice same positional parameter

Tags: nhibernate, parameters

Using NHibernate 1.x we encountered this error, suddently, during a nigthly job:

```
25/06/2012 22:50:59 (Error) : could not execute query 
[ SELECT xxxx WHERE this_.A = ? and this_.B = ? ]
Positional parameters:   
  0 117
  0 b93094d2-a934-4400-9350-53fd3dbc6494
```

You can see that index of parameter is 0 the two times. If I execute the query by myself after having replaced the two `?` with values of parameters, it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was a failure in SQL Serveur 2012 at same time (error 605).